# File, dirpath problem in my code (error help)

Tags: java

I am doing a memory game and in one of my method, I'm trying to create all cards by using File, but it could not run. It always goes to "Picture path is empty", but I want it to run.

```
/*
    Create all Cards.
     */
    public static List<Card> createAllCards(String dirPath){
        //System.out.println("create all cards");
        List<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<>();
        File file = new File(dirPath);
        File[] pictures = file.listFiles();
        //System.out.println("file：" + Arrays.toString(pictures));
        int index;
        String type = "";
        String cardPath;
        if (pictures != null){
            for (File picture : pictures) {
                index = picture.getName().lastIndexOf(".");
                if (picture.isFile()){
                    if (index > 0) {
                        type = picture.getName().substring(index + 1);
                        System.out.println("output：" + type);
                        if (type.equals("png")){
                            cardPath = picture.getPath();
                            //cardPath = cardPath.replaceAll("\\\\","\\\\\\\\");
                            cardList.add(new Card(picture.getName(),cardPath));
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }else {
            System.out.println("Picture path is empty");
        }
        return cardList;
    }
}
```

Comment: `File::listFiles` returns `null` if the given path is not a directory. You might want to put some diagnostics in your code to check you are using the right path, e.g. `if(!file.isDirectory()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid card directory: " + dirPath); ...`

Comment: Is it possible to get your email, bc it still has some error and I could not fix it, and I really need help

Comment: No SO doesn't support messaging and I'm not about to post my email address!  Add the error to your post, it's probably something simple to fix.

Answer (score 1):

The java.io.File class is obsolete.  The [java.nio.file package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) is its replacement.

The File class was part of Java 1.0 and did a poor job of reporting errors.  Many of its methods return null or false, which tells you nothing about what actually went wrong.  The classes in java.nio.file will actually throw exceptions telling you exactly what went wrong.

Specifically, you want to use the [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) and [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) classes:

```
try (DirectoryStream<Path> pictures =
    Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(dirPath), "*.png")) {

    for (Path picture : pictures) {
        if (Files.isRegularFile(picture)) {
            cardList.add(
                new Card(picture.getFileName().toString(), cardPath));
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This probably won’t make your program work, but it will give you the information you need to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I used your code and modified this, as per your requirement.

Have a look:

***NOTE: My photos folder is in the room directory***

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Card{
    String photoName,cardPath;
    public Card(String name, String cardPath2) {
        this.photoName = name;
        this.cardPath = cardPath2;
    }
}

public class readPhotos {

    public static List<Card> createAllCards(String dirPath){
        //System.out.println("create all cards");
        List<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<>();
        File file = new File(dirPath);
        File[] pictures = file.listFiles();
        //System.out.println("file：" + Arrays.toString(pictures));
        int index;
        String type = "";
        String cardPath;
        if (pictures != null){
            for (File picture : pictures) {
                index = picture.getName().lastIndexOf(".");
                if (picture.isFile()){
                    if (index > 0) {
                        type = picture.getName().substring(index + 1);
                        System.out.println("output：" + type);
                        if (type.equals("png")){
                            cardPath = picture.getPath();
                            //cardPath = cardPath.replaceAll("\\\\","\\\\\\\\");
                            cardList.add(new Card(picture.getName(),cardPath));
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }else {
            System.out.println("Picture path is empty");
        }
        return cardList;
    }

    public static void main(String...args) 
    {
        List<Card> cardList  = readPhotos.createAllCards("./photos/");

        System.out.println(cardList);
    }

}
```

add your photos path accordingly... when calling the method  `readPhotos.createAllCards("./photos/");`

[image]